# How to turn whole dataframe from string variables into numbers?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe full of answers to a survey, so each column is filled with Never, Sometimes and Always and I need to change Never to the numeric 0, sometimes to the numeric 1 and always to the numeric 2. Is there a way to apply this change to the whole dataframe instead of individual columns?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `dplyr::across()` is your friend. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I agree with @Limey! Providing a reproducible example would help a lot. In addition to `dplyr::across()` you might want to have a look at `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to melt your data frame into a long format (you then only have one value column which you can mutate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to `factor` and then to `numeric` (using Allan Cameron's sample data):

```r
df[] <- sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always"))) - 1)
df %>% 
  mutate(total = Q1 + Q2 + Q3)

   Q1 Q2 Q3 total
1   0  2  2     4
2   2  0  0     2
3   0  0  0     0
4   1  0  0     1
5   0  1  0     1
6   2  1  1     4
7   2  1  0     3
8   1  1  0     2
9   1  2  1     4
10  2  0  1     3
```

Comment: I now want to add up all the values of each row in a new column, I've tried using the tidyverse code df %>% mutate(total = Q1+Q2+Q3) but this doesnt seem to work

Comment: No luck - this error message is coming up Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: This is because you probably have not added `df[] <-` in your code, `sapply` returns a matrix. Do `sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always"))) - 1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(total = Q1 + Q2 + Q3)`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data frame looks like this:

```r
df
#>           Q1        Q2        Q3
#> 1      Never    Always    Always
#> 2     Always     Never     Never
#> 3      Never     Never     Never
#> 4  Sometimes     Never     Never
#> 5      Never Sometimes     Never
#> 6     Always Sometimes Sometimes
#> 7     Always Sometimes     Never
#> 8  Sometimes Sometimes     Never
#> 9  Sometimes    Always Sometimes
#> 10    Always     Never Sometimes
```

Then you can do

```r
df[] <- sapply(df, function(x) match(x, c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always")) - 1)
```

Which results in

```r
df
#>    Q1 Q2 Q3
#> 1   0  2  2
#> 2   2  0  0
#> 3   0  0  0
#> 4   1  0  0
#> 5   0  1  0
#> 6   2  1  1
#> 7   2  1  0
#> 8   1  1  0
#> 9   1  2  1
#> 10  2  0  1
```

---

**Reproducible data frame**

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- replicate(3, sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always"), 10, TRUE))
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df), c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using a named vector, probably more appropriate if you want more flexible in your translations.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- replicate(3, sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always"), 10, TRUE))
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = F), c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"))

t <- c(0:2)
names(t) <- c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always")

as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) t[x]))

#    Q1 Q2 Q3
# 1   0  2  2
# 2   2  0  0
# 3   0  0  0
# 4   1  0  0
# 5   0  1  0
# 6   2  1  1
# 7   2  1  0
# 8   1  1  0
# 9   1  2  1
# 10  2  0  1
```